# IIS 8 block request by JSON payload fields

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, iis, payload

I have an MVC.NET 4 web server that accepts HTTP POST request with a JSON formatted string as the request data.
I would like to add a rule in the IIS level before the request hits the server, to block request by some regex on that JSON string. Is that possible?

Comment: **to block request by some regex on that JSON string** Please explain what you mean by that...

Comment: @DaveAlperovich The request has a JSON formatted string body. so if that string matches some regex abort the request, in the same way you can match the query url  to a regex

Comment: Are you using OWIN? Or can you use HttpApplication.BeginRequest Event? Can you please elaborate why does it have to be on IIS level?

Comment: I'm not using OWIN, I want it to be in the IIS level to void more load of the the web server level needing to create another thread for each request. The reason I want to block some request is that they are not relevant to my app anymore, the come in high load and I cannot stop them from the clients side. Thanks for your time

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you block the ip instead?

Comment: I did some research, it can be done using IIS module. But only native module (written in C) can be deployed in IIS. The managed module needs to be deployed with your asp.net mvc apps I am afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creating and adding a custom [Http Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx) can solve your problem. An HTTP module is called on every request in response to the `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` events.

Comment: thanks - I'm actually looking for a way to block this on the IIS level, not the web server. Does the BeginRequest event do that?

Comment: When you say IIS level ..Did you mean implement blocking for just one specific website ?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/modules

Or use
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template

Answer (score 6):

Since you said:

> I want it to be in the IIS level to void more load of the the web
>   server level needing to create another thread for each request. The
>   reason I want to block some request is that they are not relevant to
>   my app anymore, the come in high load and I cannot stop them from the
>   clients side

You have 2 choices:

1. Request Filtering
2. URL Rewriting

Please study the [IIS 7.0 Request Filtering and URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting) article carefully to know the most important things about them. If your selection would be first one with highest priority, The [`<denyQueryStringSequences>`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/denyquerystringsequences) would be useful where it covers some filtering requirements. And for working with *regex*, you need to use the second one. the following sample rule can stop processing the request under the `<rewrite>`:

```
<rule name="Block Bad Request Strings" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
          <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=([^\"]*[^-]?>)|(?:[^\\w\\s]\\s*\\\/>)|(?:>\") />
     </conditions>
     <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden: Access is denied." statusDescription="You do not have permission" />
</rule>
```

For more information see [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)